# How to create links to compose an email in Gmail as well as Outlook specifically for iOS devices with prefill custom subject and body?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, outlook, gmail

I'm building a nextjs app where I need to compose the emails with custom subject and body . In this we have four options i.e, compose with Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo! or other. In this the other uses mailto: and opens and prefills correctly and even the Yahoo! works fine in both desktop and mobile devices (both iOS and Android) however with respect to Gmail and Outlook I was able to do it in desktop and Android, but not iOS devices.

Here is What I tried for Gmail and Outlook (which is working on desktop and Android):

[https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}](https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?subject=$%7BencodeURIComponent(subject)%7D&body=$%7BencodeURIComponent(body)%7D)

[https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=&su=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}](https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&to=&su=$%7BencodeURIComponent(subject)%7D&body=$%7BencodeURIComponent(body)%7D)

And also for iOS devices I was able to get it work with Gmail app and outlook app but these only works when users have app so that's why I am looking for something browser specific

googlegmail:///co?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}

ms-outlook://compose?&subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}

Here is the Yahoo mail link which is working in both desktop and iOS and android devices

[https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body)}](https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?subject=$%7BencodeURIComponent(subject)%7D&body=$%7BencodeURIComponent(body)%7D)

Can Someone please help me on how to achieve this with Gmail and outlook specifically for iOS on browsers?

PS: I already have mailto: working but I need something specific to Gmail and Outlook as mentioned above because mailto: opens default mail app as per the client, thanks.